# w3wp.exe crashes when calling [System.Data.Odbc]::OdbcConnection.Open()

Tags: methods, crash, odbc, w3wp

I am using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express to build a webpage that pulls data from a database to populate a drop-down list with relevant options. Everything works just dandy when I debug the page in the developer, but when I test the production page by navigating to it using IE I get a Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger window saying "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in w3wp.exe [#####]" where ##### is a number that changes each time the error presents. After some research I discovered that the error occurs when the program tries to call any OdbcConnection.Open() method. Below is some exception information from DebugDiag.

Exception Information:

```
In w3wp__TTFCUAppPages__PID__1704__Date__04_25_2013__Time_12_37_29PM__536__Second_Chance_Exception_E0434352.dmp the assembly instruction at KERNELBASE!RaiseException+58 in C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused a CLR Exception on thread 23with the following error information:



    Type: 

System.AccessViolationException



    Message: 

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Here is the call stack:

```
.NET Call Stack



Function


Full Call Stack



Function

    Arg 1

    Arg 2

    Arg 3

    Arg 4

  Source



KERNELBASE!RaiseException+58

    e0434352

    00000001

    00000005

    058bf568





clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+276

    181aba38

    00000000

    00000000

    181aba38





clr!RaiseTheException+87

    181aba38

    00000000

    00000004

    058bf760





clr!RaiseTheException+fe

    00000000

    00000004

    00000004

    5df9e75e





clr!RealCOMPlusThrow+3d

    181aba38

    00000000

    00000004

    058bf76c





clr!RealCOMPlusThrow+12

    181aba38

    00000004

    56dd0faf

    6d7e95d4





clr!Thread::RaiseCrossContextException+3e0

    00000000

    058bf7bc

    56dd0093

    03d1ea38





clr!Thread::DoADCallBack+2f3

    00000002

    6d98fe4e

    058bf878

    00000001





clr!UM2MDoADCallBack+c0

    00b44760

    ffffffff

    058bf8e0

    00000010





0x00a51ff8

    00000000

    00ac74a4

    00000003

    0000000c





webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::ProcessNotification+5b

    00ac74a4

    69f81398

    058bf95c

    6d7878af





webengine4!ProcessNotificationCallback+36

    00ac74a4

    56dd019f

    0000ffff

    00040004





clr!UnManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+195

    058bf9bf

    058bf9be

    56dd010f

    00000000





clr!ThreadpoolMgr::NewWorkerThreadStart+20b

    00000000

    56dd02f7

    00000000

    6d788499





clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+3d1

    00000000

    76f637fa

    76f637b8

    00000000





clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+4b

    00b858b8

    058bfd98

    76f6377b

    00b858b8





kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e

    00b858b8

    7dd9933f

    00000000

    00000000





ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+70

    6d877698

    00b858b8

    00000000

    00000000





ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b

    6d877698

    00b858b8

    00000000

    00000000
```

Comment: The solution was to add the ASPNET built-in user to the local DB2ADMNS and DB2USERS groups.

Start Menu
Right-click "Computer"
Choose "Manage"
Expand "Local Users and Groups"
Click "Groups"
Find the "DB2ADMNS" and "DB2USERS" groups.
Add the "ASPNET" user to each of those groups.

Comment: Can you make that an Answer, and Accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the ASPNET built-in user to the local DB2ADMNS and DB2USERS groups. Start Menu Right-click "Computer" Choose "Manage" Expand "Local Users and Groups" Click "Groups" Find the "DB2ADMNS" and "DB2USERS" groups. Add the "ASPNET" user to each of those groups.